# How to override the NSObject methods without inheriting from NSObject in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, inheritance, objective-c-runtime

I actually want to know how to access the `encodeWithCoder`, `init` etc methods from the `NSObject` or any other class without inheriting from `NSObject` class.

Because I read that if we inherit from the `NSObject` class then it has performance issues in Swift or similar performance to the Objective - C.

So please let me know how to do it.

Comment: i dont think it has to be an NSObject, it just needs to conform to the NSCoding protocol

Answer (score 1):

You want to override a super class method from a class that doesn't inherit from that super class, this doesn't make sense. If you need to use encodeWithCoder method, you'll have to extend NSObject class or any other class that conforms to NSCoding protocol. Otherwise you can create your custom class that conforms to NSCoding protocol and implement the same functionality in encodeWithCoder method.

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html)

> Any class that does not inherit from another class is known as a base class.
>
> NOTE
>
> Swift classes do not inherit from a universal base class. Classes you
>   define without specifying a superclass automatically become base
>   classes for you to build upon.